# Struggling with a bug that knockout.js me

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I fear this is something as embarrassing as a typo, but since I´m stuck on this and quite desperate I´m willing to pay with pride. ;)

This is my case:

```
Task = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.TaskId = data.TaskId;
    self.TaskName = ko.observable(data.TaskName);
}


ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Tasks = ko.observableArray(); 
    self.SelectedTask = ko.observable();
}


$.getJSON("/myService/GetAllTasks", 
    function (tData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(tData, function (item) {
            return new Task(item)
        });

        self.Tasks(mappedTasks); // Populate Tasks-array...
});


self.newTaskItem = function () {

    var newitem = new Task({
        TaskId: -1,
        TaskName: "enter taskname here"
    });

    self.Tasks.push(newitem);    // THIS ONE CRASH
    self.Tasks().push(newitem);  // BUT SUBSTITUTED WITH THIS ONE IT RUNS ON...
    self.editTaskItem(newitem);
};

self.editTaskItem = function (item) {

    self.SelectedTask(item);     // UNTIL TIL LINE WHERE IT CRASHES FOR GOOD...

    self.showEditor(true);  // makes Task-edior visible in HTML
};
```

I also hava an "self.SelectedTask.subscription" in my file, but leaving it out of the code makes no difference.

I also should mention that my database table is empty, so the getJSON returns no data to the mappedTasks, leaving self.Tasks() = [ ] (according to Firebug)

I have fixed the incorrectly closed tags in my code.

Part 2:

Decided after a while to redo my code from the starting point. It got me one step further.

The code now stops on the second of these lines (in "self.newTaskItem"):

```
    self.Tasks.push(newitem);
    self.SelectedTask(newitem);  // Here it fails.
```

These two observables are connected in my HTML like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: Tasks, optionsText: '$root.TaskName', value: SelectedTask"</select>
```

Comment: Your `$.getJSON` invocation is missing the closing `)`

Comment: Most decent editors should have syntax highlighting that would detect issues like this, but using jslint with very conservative settings is also a good strategy.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a type in here. It is closed in my code. i use VS2012 which (I think) is quite good on these syntax errors highlightning.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: To never plead guilty to stupidity is the biggest stupidity of all... ;) That said I've scored a hatfull in the first half... :-o

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `ViewModel()` function never gets closed. Add a closing `}` to wherever you want that function declaration to end. It looks to me (based on your formatting) that you want this:

```
ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Tasks = ko.observableArray(); 
    self.SelectedTask = ko.observable();
}
```

Additionally, you need to close your`$.getJson` call with a `);`:

```
$.getJSON("/myService/GetAllTasks", 
    function (tData) {
        var mappedTasks = $.map(tData, function (item) {
            return new Task(item)
        });

        self.Tasks(mappedTasks); // Populate Tasks-array...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what your problem is or what error you are getting but this is what I would do - change your Task = function to function Task -

```
function Task(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.TaskId = data.TaskId;
}
```

By saying Task = function without using a var in front of it you are registering Task in the global namespace, not a good idea.  Same thing with your view model...  Fix it if you can still...

```
self.newTaskItem = function () {

    var newitem = new Task({
        // Your Task is looking for a TaskId, not a TextBatchId
        TaskId: 1
    });

    self.Tasks.push(newitem);
    self.editTaskItem(newitem);
};
```

Also, you are creating a TextBatchId where I think your Task object is looking for a TaskId.  Fix that, or if you are doing it on purpose for some reason please show your view code and give a better explanation of what is going wrong and what errors you see.

Comment: Thanx PW Kad. Never be in a hurry is todays lesson for me to take out of here. I am simplifying my code to present it here. Not very successfully I'm afraid. I actually do have a namespace, but I don't think I fully understand it.

Comment: Just to be clear: My problem is not the missing parenthesis. My problem is that self.Tasks.push(newitem) fails. The code stops there. I.e. in firebug it goes straight into some jquery-min.js function. 4 more clicks om stopover and no more life.

I even tried to insert som data into the db via SQL server manager. same thing happens. TaskId (not TextbatchId which is typo no 300 in this post... sorry...) does not have to be a observable I think, as it´s the PK in the database and I never edit it (i have intensional left out the editable fields like TaskName,  taskDescription etc.

Comment: Here´s the debug (from Firebug):
newitem
 Object { TextbatchId=-1}
self.Textbatches()
 []
insertAt
 function()
__proto__
 function()
callBaseMethod
 function()
getBaseMethod
 function()
getBaseType
 function()
getInterfaces
 function()
getName
 function()
implementsInterface
 function()
inheritsFrom
 function()
initializeBase
 function()
isImplementedBy
 function()
isInstanceOfType
 function()
registerClass
 function()
registerEnum
 function()
registerInterface
 function()
resolveInheritance
 function()
prototype
 Object {}
__proto__
 []
constructor
 Array()

Fails on: self.Tasks.push(newitem)

Comment: For whoever wants a look at the complete ViewModel:
http://jsfiddle.net/kX6ss/1/

PS. I am not very experienced in javascript or coding... ;)

Answer (score 1):

(assuming the unclosed stuff isn't present in your real code)

In `Task`, `TaskId` isn't an observable, so when you set `SelectedTask` to a particular task your editor fields won't properly update (it's a fairly common mistake to assume that the elements of an `observableArray` are themselves `observable`, but they aren't unless you explicitly make them so).

Comment: Hmm, thanks ebohlman.
I doubt that´s the problem as I´m not planning to edit the TaskId.

I have stripped my code down to the bone. Firebugs tells me this:
self.Tasks = [ ] 
newitem = Object { TaskId=-1   TaskTitle=c() }  
self.TaskTitle() = "any Text..."

Then when I step into the code line  "self.Tasks.push(newitem);"
Firebug first goes to knockout.js line 59 the query-min.js line 3 then line 1 before it stops. The line after "self.Tasks.push(newitem);" is never reached.